# How to specify content-type using the Grails REST client builder plugin?

Tags: rest, grails

I'm using the Grails REST client builder plugin (https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder) like so:

```
final def rest = new RestBuilder(connectTimeout:connectTimeout, readTimeout:readTimeout)
final def resp = rest.get(uri)
```

So the server always returns the result as XML - how do I (the client) specify that I want the result as JSON?

Comment: The **"contentType"** should do the job. But does the service provider support JSON? If not then you have to convert XML to JSON on your end, or use XML instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the content type is done through the contentType method. The [documetnation](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder) points this out with the following example.

```
        def resp = rest.put("http://repo.grails.org/grails/api/security/groups/test-group"){
        auth System.getProperty("artifactory.user"), System.getProperty("artifactory.pass")
        contentType "application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.security.Group+json"
        json {
            name = "test-group"
            description = "A temporary test group"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
final def rest = new RestBuilder(connectTimeout:connectTimeout, readTimeout:readTimeout)
final def resp = rest.get(uri) {
  accept "application/json"  # Add this bit
}
```

Comment: Can you explain any advantage of this solution over the accepted answer?

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me.  I think the accepted answer will only work with a "PUT".  For a "GET" you need to use "accept".  In my case i was getting JSON, but wanted XML...

Comment: Surely accepting `application/json` means that you're getting JSON, not XML.  Also, the HTTP method shouldn't affect the returned payload.  Interesting that it works this way for you.